# IOS Affine Transforms

Tags: ios, cgcontext

Does an affine transform reposition the content within the view or transform the view's output?

In my experiments, it appears to be the latter. If I apply a translation moving the contents off the view the right, I do not appear to be able to draw in the area within the view to the left.

As requested: I would like to be able to create a scrolling view that rotates. Imagine viewing part of a globe viewed parallel to the axis. The content has to rotate with scrolling.

If I use an affine transform, it appears that the view display is transformed, not the content within the view. If I scroll the content to the right using an affine transform, I get a black area to the left visible in the view that I cannot draw in.

I am trying to confirm whether my interpretation of what is happening is correct. If so, I need to try a different approach.

Comment: Unclear, too vague. Please show what you are doing and explain what you are hoping to accomplish.